# How to efficiently find clusters of like elements in a multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array like so:

```
array = [[a, b, b, a, a, b]
         [a, a, b, a, b, a]]
```

What I would like to do is identify the clusters of like elements i.e. look at each element and find a group of 'a's based on whether there is another 'a' above, below, to the left or right of it such that the program finds an array like so:

[*a*, **b**, **b**, ***a***, ***a***, b]

[*a*, *a*, **b**, ***a***, b, a]

It would return an array like so ["0:0", "1:0", "1:1"] for the first cluster of 'a's

My question is, **what is the most efficient way of doing this in python?**

FYI: I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: Do you want to identify the clusters and the locations of the clusters' elements? Or is your goal to just measure the sizes of each cluster (the number of elements each contains)?

Comment: @MartinValgur sorry for that; what I want is to return an array with the location of each of the elements within that cluster (e.g. return ["0:0", "1:0", "1:1"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [scipy.ndimage.measurements](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html#module-scipy.ndimage.measurements):

```
from scipy import ndimage 

def find_clusters(array):
    clustered = np.empty_like(array)
    unique_vals = np.unique(array)
    cluster_count = 0
    for val in unique_vals:
        labelling, label_count = ndimage.label(array == val)
        for k in range(1, label_count + 1):
            clustered[labelling == k] = cluster_count
            cluster_count += 1
    return clustered, cluster_count

clusters, cluster_count = find_clusters(array)
print("Found {} clusters:".format(cluster_count))
print(clusters)

ones = np.ones_like(array, dtype=int)
cluster_sizes = ndimage.sum(ones, labels=clusters, index=range(cluster_count)).astype(int)
com = ndimage.center_of_mass(ones, labels=clusters, index=range(cluster_count))
for i, (size, center) in enumerate(zip(cluster_sizes, com)):
    print("Cluster #{}: {} elements at {}".format(i, size, center))
```

yields:

```
Found 6 clusters:
[[0 3 3 1 1 4]
 [0 0 3 1 5 2]]
Cluster #0: 3 elements at (0.66666666666666663, 0.33333333333333331)
Cluster #1: 3 elements at (0.33333333333333331, 3.3333333333333335)
Cluster #2: 1 elements at (1.0, 5.0)
Cluster #3: 3 elements at (0.33333333333333331, 1.6666666666666667)
Cluster #4: 1 elements at (0.0, 5.0)
Cluster #5: 1 elements at (1.0, 4.0)
```

To get the locations of elements within each cluster, you can do `clusters == cluster_id`, e.g.

```
In [126]:
clusters == 3
Out[126]:
array([[False,  True,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Or, to get the bounding box of each cluster you can use `find_objects` from the same SciPy package:

```
In [128]:
# +1 because zeros would be ignored otherwise
scipy.ndimage.measurements.find_objects(clusters+1)
Out[128]:
[(slice(0, 2, None), slice(0, 2, None)),
 (slice(0, 2, None), slice(3, 5, None)),
 (slice(1, 2, None), slice(5, 6, None)),
 (slice(0, 2, None), slice(1, 3, None)),
 (slice(0, 1, None), slice(5, 6, None)),
 (slice(1, 2, None), slice(4, 5, None))]
```

Comment: Could you have it return the clusters indicating their position within the multidimensional array possibly?  Thanks!

Comment: I think my edit covers that now. Just do `clusters == cluster_id` to get the exact locations.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Might take a little while for me to wrap my head around this, but it looks great :D

Comment: The functions in `scipy.ndimage.measurements` are also exposed as functions in `scipy.ndimage`. So you could for example, use `from scipy import ndimage` and call `ndimage.find_objects`.

Comment: @unutbu Thanks! It was starting to get pretty ugly with the full package name at every other line.